# C++ - How can I POST(http request) an image to SkyBiomtery API using CppREST SDK?

Tags: c++, http, post, get

I'm connecting to [SkyBiomtery API](https://skybiometry.com/documentation/) in my C++ code using CPPREST SDK (Casablanca).

The [SkyBiometry API](https://skybiometry.com/documentation/) accepts both GET, POST requests. I need to send the image to the [SkyBiometry could service](https://skybiometry.com). Either I save the image on some public server and send them the URL of the image in the request.

OR (Which is my question) They say that "Note: in case where you want to POST images instead of specifying urls, request to the method must be formed as a MIME multi-part message sent using POST data. Each argument should be specified as a separate chunk of form data."

How can I send the image data in POST request using the CPP Rest SDK?